# Gridview databinding with structure not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a structure defined with structure inside a class and after populating the structure I am binding it to a gridview. At the time of debugging the gridview_OnRowDataBound(...), the gridview cells  show no data. However, the gridview on UI shows the data. Not sure if its the postback, but I verified that there is no change in page_load at the time of postback. Any pointers would help.

```
public partial Class1
{
....
....
        [Serializable]
        public struct StructSelectedSiteList
        {
            public string SiteName
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string RncName
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string Status
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public int TaskId
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string IssueType
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string ReworkSource
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string ReworkReason
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        };
....
```

Declaring the locals

```
var lstSites = new List<StructSelectedSiteList>();
```

Populating the structure

```
// populate the struct for selected sites
                        StructSelectedSiteList structSelectedSiteList = new StructSelectedSiteList();
                        structSelectedSiteList.SiteName = lblSiteName.Text;
                        structSelectedSiteList.Status = ddSiteStatusUpdate.SelectedValue.Trim();
                        structSelectedSiteList.TaskId = taskId;
                        structSelectedSiteList.IssueType = ddIssues.SelectedValue.Trim();
                        structSelectedSiteList.ReworkSource = reworkGrp.SelectedValue;
                        structSelectedSiteList.ReworkReason = ddReworkReason.SelectedValue;
                        structSelectedSiteList.RncName = lblRNCName.Text;
```

lstSites.Add(structSelectedSiteList);

In each gridview row data binding

```
      protected void gvSelectedSites_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        { 

....
....
// check if task id is bound
             if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
             {
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("data contents - " + e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("data contents - " + e.Row.Cells[1].Text);
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("data contents - " + e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("data contents - " + e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("data contents - " + e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("data contents - " + e.Row.Cells[5].Text);
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("data contents - " + e.Row.Cells[6].Text);
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("data contents - " + e.Row.Cells[7].Text);
             }
}
```

UI gridview design

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSelectedSites" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True"
                                CellPadding="4" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." Font-Names="Segoe UI"
                                Width="605px" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                EmptyDataRowStyle-Font-Bold="true" EmptyDataRowStyle-ForeColor="Red" OnRowDataBound="gvSelectedSites_OnRowDataBound">
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                                <Columns>                                        
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Site Name">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSiteName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SiteName")%>'>
                                            </asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RNC Name">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblRNCName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RncName")%>'>
                                            </asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%>'>
                                            </asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Issue Type">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblIssueType" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IssueType")%>'>
                                            </asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task" Visible="false">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblTaskId" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TaskId")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>                                        
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rework Source">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblReworkSource" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReworkSource")%>'>
                                            </asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rework Reason">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblReworkReason" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReworkReason")%>'>
                                            </asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Site Comments">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSiteComments" runat="server" Width="350px" Height="50px" TextMode="MultiLine"
                                                Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe grid has the data, you are just looking in the wrong place. Note that for every field you are using a template, meaning the cell itself does have a text but some inner controls instead. Try accessing these controls and most likely you will see the data:

```
// example for site name
Label label = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSiteName");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("data contents - " + label.Text);
```

Comment: thanks! I was able to see the data after accessing from the inner controls.

Comment: you raised a very imp (one which I missed!) concept...field is a template hence cannot directly access the values :)